# Distance of rays from the center of a chord to the arc

Tags: arc-length

I have search the web for an answer.  Here is what I know.  I know the radius (500") of the arc.  I know the arc height(48") from the center of the chord. Starting at the center of the cord find the length to the arc every 15 degrees. If the formula to find the answer does not input values provided more than likely I will not be able to understand.

[Answer I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYP7N.png)

Comment: So you have a circle with radius 500 units and a chord perpendicular to a radius which crosses the radius a distance 452 units from the center of the circle and you wish to know the distance from the center of the chord to the arc of the chord as a function of the angle between the chord and the segment connecting the center of the chord to the arc?

Comment: That is correct.  After looking at your diagram it appears to be what I am trying to figure out.  I will try to work your formula to see if it is what I am looking for.  I am checking my answers using a CAD program.  Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Distance from chord center to arc as function of angle]

The point $C$ has coordinates $(0,452)$. In order to find the length of segment $CG$ as a function of the angle $\alpha$ one can first find the coordinates of the point $G$ as functions of $\alpha$. The point $G$ is one of the two points of intersection (the one with positive $x$-coordinate) of the two graphs:

\begin{equation}
y=x\tan\alpha+452
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x^2+y^2=500^2
\end{equation}

Substituting the first equation into the second gives

\begin{equation}
x^2+(x\tan\alpha+452)^2=500
\end{equation}

which can be solved for the non-negative value of $x$ in terms of $\alpha$.

Then using the first of the two equations above, one can find $y$ as a function of $\alpha$.

Then one can derive the length of $CG$ as a function of $\alpha$ for $0\le\alpha\le\tfrac{\pi}{2}$. For $\tfrac{\pi}{2}<\alpha\le\pi$ the distance is the same as for the acute angle $\pi-\alpha$.

Comment: Again I would like to think you for the formula you have provided.  I am unable to find the length of CG.  Please step through your formula until the answer is given.  I have tried to understand what I need to do by going to a few other sites but all do not give specific examples that I can figure out that apply to what I am looking for.  Your formula appears elegant but is still beyond my capabilities.

Comment: I believe that this is a problem which would be easier to work in a general rather than a specific case. What I mean is use a unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and a horizontal line $y=b$. Then find the lengths from the center of the chord to the arc as a function of $\alpha$ in this simpler setting. Then to solve the case when the circle radius is $500$ and the 'height' of the chord is $48$ you would let $b=\dfrac{500-48}{500}=0.904$ and multiply the resulting distances by $500$ to get the distances for a circle of radius $500$. I will take a look at that and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I find that for the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the horizontal chord lying on $y=b$ where $0\le b<1$ the length of $CG$ in the diagram is $\dfrac{\sqrt{\sec^2\alpha-b^2}-b\tan\alpha}{\sec\alpha}$. In your case you would use $b=0.904$ and multiply the result by $500$ to get $|OG|=500\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{\sec^2\alpha-0.904^2}-(0.904)\tan\alpha}{\sec\alpha}$ for acute angles $\alpha$. For obtuse angles $\alpha$, $|OG|$ would be the same distance as for the acute angle $180^\circ-\alpha$.

Comment: Segment CG should be 126.6975

Comment: When I wrote $OG$ I meant $CG$. But for which angle $\alpha$ are you computing $CG$? The value will be different for each angle from $0^\circ$ to $90^\circ$.

Comment: See original post for a Cad drawing of the answer I am trying to find a formula for.  Click on "Answer I am Looking for".  Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct value for $15^\circ$. After computing it, since there is no secant function on my calculator I see a better formula can be had by multiplying numerator and denominator by $\cos\alpha$ to get $|CG|=500\left[\sqrt{1-(0.904\cos\alpha)^2}-(0.904)\sin\alpha\right]$.

Comment: Note that the formula $|CG|=500\left[\sqrt{1-(0.904\cos\alpha)^2}-(0.904)\sin\alpha\right]$ also gives the result 213.7662 when $\alpha=0$ which agrees with your CAD diagram so I am confident that the formula is correct. You should be able to use it to find the correct distance for other angles if necessary.

Comment: The most general formula for an arc of radius $R$ and height $H$ would be $$\text{LENGTH }=\sqrt{R^2-[(R-H)\cos\alpha]^2}-(R-H)\sin\alpha$$ in case you ever meet a similar problem